# Having same configuration on Ignite client when already have configuration on Ignite server

Tags: ignite

Okay 
Here is my Ignite Server cfg code.

```
     @Bean("serverCfg")
    public IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() throws Exception {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration(); cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServer");
    cfg.setSqlSchemas("public");
    TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

      TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new 
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

      ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47510"));

      discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);
    // cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheOrganizationsCache()
                                                          , 
cacheRolesCache(), cacheUsersCache(),

cacheUsersRolesCache(), cacheGroupsCache(),

cacheGroupusersCache(), cacheGlobalPermissionsCache(),

cacheTemplatesCache(), cachePasswordsCache()
                                                         );

    return cfg;
}
```

And Here is my Ignite Client Code.

```
@Bean
public Ignite createConfiguration() throws Exception {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    cfg.setClientMode(true); cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerClient");


      TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

      TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new 
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

      ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47510"));

      discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

      cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);       
      cfg.setCacheConfiguration( cacheOrganizationsCache(),   cacheRolesCache(),
      cacheUsersCache(), cacheUsersRolesCache(), cacheGroupsCache(),
      cacheGroupusersCache() );

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
    ignite.cluster().active(true);

    return ignite;
}
```

So My question is do I had to have same piece of code that contains all cache configurations including data source at client side also?
How to avoid this code redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to supply all cache configurations on client. Once first server node comes up, it will start all caches, other nodes will be able to use them regardless whether they have them in their own configs or not. Any new caches will be created when nodes join. Cache configurations will never be changed on join of new nodes with differing cfgs of existing caches.

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/36498/alamar can i have some example code. Since when i tried without cache cfg's at client side it throws exception.

Comment: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).

Comment: This means you need to configure Data Source for your Cache Store, supply it as part of Spring context on client node. If you don't have any, I can see how you may need to actually specify cache configuration, to provide DataSource through it.

Comment: I dont wanna supply cache store in client cfg.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to do that. I guess you can implement a lazy Cache Store which will only initialize on use.

Comment: here is my POC code. look at server and client 1." https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zB7UonHBabAFv2fRzdKwF0n-mwSAQ-ha " . it is working fine but not in my actual application. plzz look at my code and help.

Comment: I recommend writing to apache ignite user list, since SO is ill-suited to debugging reproducer tarballs.